# Multiple page size and orientation setting in power bi report builder

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, sqlreportingservice

I am working on a report project using **Power Bi Report Builder** `version 15.7.1740.1` (latest).

And I have a request from the customer to create only the first page as portrait as cover page and the remaining pages orientation will be landscape.

The problem is that the builder has only one canvas page and the orientation for this canvas will ignore the size of each page even I use the subreport is not working correctly.

The customer uses this report to an export pdf version, So any idea or workaround how to fix it?

This is the example of the request

[image]

Comment: Can you simply rotate everything on the cover page by 90 degrees and then you can leave it setup as landscape?

Comment: It will display correctly in PDF, and this is the problem.

Comment: "*It will display correctly in PDF, and this is the problem*" ? What is the problem? I just tested this and it works as expected. If it's not working for you, share the report design and current output.

Comment: @AlanSchofield Sorry for the typo error, I met to say in pdf will be an issue because the first page will be rotated 90 degrees (Horizontal view) and the remaining pages are normal pages (vertical)

Comment: I add an image for the Expected Pdf